# Create multiple server using Terraform on Azure

Tags: azure, terraform

I am creating multiple servers on Azure using Terraform template in a same Azure "Resource group", However when i try to run the template for individual servers each time, it is deleting the previous server while creating for next one.

Any idea how i can i reuse the same template for creating multiple server in a same Resource Group.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share your template?

Comment: You had better check this [example](http://www.thehyperadvisor.com/cloud-computing/terraform-your-azure-infrastructure/) to create multiple VMs.

Answer (score 1):

Terraform is intended to be idempotent, meaning that reapplying the same template makes no changes. If you edit the template, Terraform will edit the environment to reflect any changes or deletions.

If you need multiple VMs, you have at least two options:

- Define multiple VM resources in your template.
- Define a VM scale set and simply specify the number of VMs that you need.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this, Here is what i did.
I created 2 separate .tf files under different folders.

1) For creating Resource group, NSG, Storage account, Vnet
2) For creating public ip, network interface and VM itself.

So i could use second configuration file for creating multiple server by just changing the values though parameters